# How to merge clib functions into a table using LuaJIT and FFI?

Tags: lua, ffi, luajit

I have a table/object defined in Lua.  I'm trying to add some methods from a C-API dll.  I could attach the methods one at a time, but there are a lot of them. The last line of the code below is how I would like to do it.  It is supposed to merge the methods into the `Utilities` object so that I don't have to do them one at a time.  I'm getting the following error:

```
bad argument #1 to 'pairs' (table expected, got userdata)"  const char *
```

Here is some sample code:

```
Utilities = {}

--
-- Other Code that defines/attaches methods to Utilities
-- 

-- Define some methods from my utilities.dll
local ffi = require("ffi")
ffi.cdef[[
void LogThis(const char * format, ...);
]]

local utilities_ffi = ffi.load("utilities")

-- This works
utilities_ffi.LogThis("hello world")

-- merge the two tables together (this fails)
for k,v in pairs(utilities_ffi) do Utilities[k] = v end
```

FFI must be returning a userdata object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFI library objects don't support iteration; you can't run `pairs` over them. You'll have to write an assignment for each function manually.

Also keep in mind that it's faster to access C functions directly from the library object, rather than storing them in a table (or even a local variable) and accessing them there. See the last section of [the FFI tutorial](http://luajit.org/ext_ffi_tutorial.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
local function get(C, k)
  return C[k]
end
function merge(C1, C2)
   return setmetatable({}, {__index = function(t, k)
      local ok, ret = pcall(get, C, k)
      local v = ok and ret or C2[k]
      t[k] = v --cache it
   end})   
end

Utilities = merge(utilities_ffi, other_ffi)
```